# Numpy hstack - "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions" - but they do

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to join two numpy arrays. In one I have a set of columns/features after running TF-IDF on a single column of text. In the other I have one column/feature which is an integer. So I read in a column of train and test data, run TF-IDF on this, and then I want to add another integer column because I think this will help my classifier learn more accurately how it should behave.

Unfortunately, I am getting the error in the title when I try and run `hstack` to add this single column to my other numpy array.

Here is my code :

```
  #reading in test/train data for TF-IDF
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,2])

  #reading in labels for training
  y = np.array(p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";"))[:,-2]

  #reading in single integer column to join
  AlexaTrainData = p.read_csv('FinalCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]]
  AlexaTestData = p.read_csv('FinalTestCSVFin.csv', delimiter=";")[["alexarank"]]
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AlexaTestData.append(AlexaTrainData)

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1) #tf-idf object
  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None) #Classifier
  X_all = traindata + testdata #adding test and train data to put into tf-idf
  lentrain = len(traindata) #find length of train data
  tfv.fit(X_all) #fit tf-idf on all our text
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all) #transform it
  X = X_all[:lentrain] #reduce to size of training set
  AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo = AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo[:lentrain] #reduce to size of training set
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:] #reduce to size of training set

  #printing debug info, output below : 
  print "X.shape => " + str(X.shape)
  print "AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape => " + str(AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape)
  print "X_all.shape => " + str(X_all.shape)

  #line we get error on
  X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
```

Below is the output and error message :

```
X.shape => (7395, 238377)
AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape => (7395, 1)
X_all.shape => (10566, 238377)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-2b310887b5e4> in <module>()
     31 print "X_all.shape => " + str(X_all.shape)
     32 #X = np.column_stack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
---> 33 X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
     34 sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
     35 X = sc.transform(X)

C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.pyc in hstack(tup)
    271     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    272     if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 273         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    274     else:
    275         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

What is causing my problem here? How can I fix this? As far as I can see I should be able to join these columns? What have I misunderstood?

Thank you.

Edit :

Using the method in the answer below gets the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-640ef6dd335d> in <module>()
---> 36 X = np.column_stack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
     37 sc = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
     38 X = sc.transform(X)

C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.pyc in column_stack(tup)
    294             arr = array(arr,copy=False,subok=True,ndmin=2).T
    295         arrays.append(arr)
--> 296     return _nx.concatenate(arrays,1)
    297 
    298 def dstack(tup):

ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Interestingly, I tried to print the `dtype` of X and this worked fine :

```
X.dtype => float64
```

However, trying to print the dtype of `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo` like so :

```
print "AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.dtype => " + str(AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.dtype)
```

produces :

```
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Does `allAlexaAndGoogleInfo.append(X)` work?  My guess is that if you want to combine a `DataFrame` object with an `numpy.ndarray`, you need to use methods provided by Pandas.  Or convert the `DataFrame` to a plain `numpy` array.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As `X` is a sparse array, instead of `numpy.hstack`, use `scipy.sparse.hstack` to join the arrays. In my opinion the error message is kind of misleading here.

This minimal example illustrates the situation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

X = sparse.rand(10, 10000)
xt = np.random.random((10, 1))
print 'X shape:', X.shape
print 'xt shape:', xt.shape
print 'Stacked shape:', np.hstack((X,xt)).shape
#print 'Stacked shape:', sparse.hstack((X,xt)).shape #This works
```

Based on the following output

```
X shape: (10, 10000)
xt shape: (10, 1)
```

one may expect that the `hstack` in the following line will work, but the fact is that it throws this error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

So, use `scipy.sparse.hstack` when you have a sparse array to stack.

---

In fact I have answered this as a comment in your another questions, and you mentioned that another error message pops up:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O'))
```

First of all, `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo` does not have a `dtype` as it is a `DataFrame`. To get it's underlying numpy array, simply use `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.values`. Check its `dtype`. Based on the error message, it has a `dtype` of `object`, which means that it might contain non-numerical elements like strings.

This is a minimal example that reproduces this situation:

```
X = sparse.rand(100, 10000)
xt = np.random.random((100, 1))
xt = xt.astype('object') # Comment this to fix the error
print 'X:', X.shape, X.dtype
print 'xt:', xt.shape, xt.dtype
print 'Stacked shape:', sparse.hstack((X,xt)).shape
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O'))
```

So, check if there is any non-numerical values in `AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo` and repair them, before doing the stacking.

Comment: The `np.hstack` is able to coerce types, e.g. `np.hstack((X.A,xt))` works, producing an array with dtype object.  `sparse.hstack` also works if you explicitly cast the arrays, e.g.   `sparse.hstack((X.astype(object), xt))`

Comment: OMFG I was pulling my hair and banging my head before I saw this. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Use `.column_stack`. Like so:

```
X = np.column_stack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))
```

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

> Take a sequence of 1-D arrays and stack them as columns to make a
>   single 2-D array. 2-D arrays are stacked as-is, just like with hstack.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated my question above to show the error message this produces.

Comment: What is the output of the 3 `str(*.shape)` lines?

Comment: It's in the question I posted above if the markup on this gets annoying, but the output is : `X.shape => (7395, 238377)`, 
`AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape => (7395, 1)` and
`X_all.shape => (10566, 238377)`. Thanks :)

Comment: Try `X.resize(AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.shape)` then `X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo))`.

Comment: This line then throws the error `AttributeError: resize not found`. Thank you for the idea though! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
X = np.hstack((X, AllAlexaAndGoogleInfo.values))
```

I don't have a running Pandas module, so can't test it.  But the DataFrame documentation describes `values  Numpy representation of NDFrame`.  `np.hstack` is a `numpy` function, and as such knows nothing about the internal structure of the `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this also falls victim to : `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions `:(

Comment: I tried to print this; but I believe pandas reads it in as a DataFrame object so it throws the error ` 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`. I am not sure how to get around this issue. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: But isn't there a way of getting an `ndarray` expression of that DataFrame?  From the documentation it looked like `values` would do that.  There's also a 'as_matrix' method.  What about `ftypes`?  I also see `dtypes` in the documentation.  A DataFrame may contain an `ndarray`, but it is not itself an `ndarray`.